# Is there any discernible difference between these two sentences?

Tags: sentence-construction, tense, present-perfect, past-perfect, auxiliary-verbs

He has been slacking off on the couch just before you got here?

He had been slacking off on the couch just before you got here?

Comment: The first is not idiomatic in my English; the second is. But the most idiomatic for me would be "He was slacking off ..."

Comment: It doesn't work in mine either. "has been" means up to the time of the utterance; "just before you got here" introduces a contradicting time limit.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence with "has been" implies that he was slacking off continuously up until the person being addressed arrived. The second with "Had been", at least in my English, implies that he stopped slacking off before the person being addressed arrived.

https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-had-been-and-has-been

Comment: So, my second question implies he stopped slacking off just before that person got here (in a much distant past) relative to my first question where he just stopped slacking off at the moment (in the present).

Comment: I reckon there's a conflicting timeline.